# How do I add a secondary shortcut / shortcut alias on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, mission-control

I would like to switch Mission Control desktops with another button while still keeping the normal ctrl + arrow shortcut. Is this possible in any feasable way without 3rd party apps?

I'm trying to achieve this as my mouse supports key remappings, so I could assign the side buttons to like F17 and F18. I don't want to overwrite the original shortcut in case I have the mouse on another profile when I'm gaming, for example.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure it would be simpler to remap the mouse globally to the same as you use for default, then make exceptions in specific app remaps.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. My mouse does not support macros on macOS

Comment: Your mouse doesn't really need to 'support' anything. Its driver does. What driver are you using? In fact, what mouse/Mac/OS are you using - we have no idea of any aspect of your setup, so all we can do is guess.

Comment: Using macOS 13.3.1, mouse is SteelSeries Aerox 3 Wireless, and I am not using any 3rd party drivers as of right now, since SteelSeries does not currently offer a fully Ventura-compatible version of the SteelSeriesEngine3Driver.kext. The mouse can do keybindings on board, which is what I would like to use, so I don't think which mouse or driver am I using is relevant. Remember, the original post is simply a question of how does one add a secondary keyboard shortcut or shortcut alias on macOS.

Comment: Well, as the direct answer to that is "you can't" I was trying to think of another way to do it.